# why main() and if __name__=='__main__': main() is causing trouble?

Tags: python-2.7, program-entry-point

```
def removal(DataList, n):
    if len(DataList) < 2*n:
        print "Not enough elements!"
    for i in range(n):
        DataList.remove(min(DataList))
        DataList.remove(max(DataList))
    return sorted(DataList)

def main():
    inputs = []
    while True:
        inp = raw_input("Please enter a new integer, press ENTER if you want to stop: ")
        if inp == "":
            break
        else:
            inputs.append(inp)
    removal(inputs,2)
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
main()
```

I got a `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`
At a meanwhile, if I do not write my code in the main() and if **name**=='**main**', I'd be fine with the following code.

```
def removal(DataList, n):
    #return to a sorted list with n smallest and n largest numbers removed. 
    for i in range(n):
        DataList.remove(min(DataList))
        DataList.remove(max(DataList))
    return sorted(DataList)
inputs = []
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Please enter a new integer, press ENTER if you want to stop: ")
    if inp == "":
        break
    else:
        inputs.append(inp)
removal(inputs,2)
```

Could somebody explain why it doesn't work in former and how should I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
main()
```

You're calling the `main` function twice (when your program is run as the main program), so after you enter a series of numbers and press another Enter to end the input, `main` calls `removal` to do the intended operations, which do not produce any output, and returns to the main program to start another call to `main`, which prompts for another series of number input. If at this point you simply press another Enter, you would end up with an empty list for the `inputs` list, which your `removal` function does not handle properly and would call `min` with the empty list, causing the said exception of `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`.

Comment: oops. Thanks for the quick answer.